# How would I move a plus sign character (+) in excel from beginging of a word to a end?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Transform from:

+WordA +WordB

Transform To:

WordA+ WordB+

What would be the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit shorter

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,2,999)," +","+ ")&"+"
```

If the cell is expected to have more than 999 characters, up that number.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "+WordA +WordB" is in cell `A1`, this formula will work:

```
= SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)," +","+ ")&"+"
```